# How to pull and push commit in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to pull a file from the gitlab and add a sentence to it and then push it. However, I am not sure how to do it.

How do I pull the project which is uploaded on gitlab and append a sentence to a file, then commit the change and push the commit to the server?

Comment: Have you clone the respository locally, where you want to add a sentence to a file?

Comment: How do i do that?